# How can I connect to local Meteor's mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How can I connect to the local Meteor's local mongoDB? Fyi, I want to use robomongo as the client. Where can I get the authentication details etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using robomongo too

1) Just open robomongo,

2) Create new connection,

3)Give address `localhost` and port `3001`

4) Click connect

**Note:** Meteor must be running to access the  database

While you are creating new connection there is an `authentication` tab,there u can create username and password for db

Comment: Works. By default meteor's mongodb does not require any username/password?

Comment: Yeah,no need of uname/pwd

Answer (score 1):

enter command `meteor mongo` in the project directory while you are running the project. it will connect to a mongo shell of the project where you can see the mongo url.

example:

`$ meteor mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:3001/meteor`

Comment: works! Lol now I need to learn how to query from mongo shell >.>